# How to filter table in R based on keywords in excel csv?

Tags: r

I have one data frame and one CSV file. The data frame is a table of URLs and their related metadata. The CSV file is a list of keywords in a table that is grouped into categories.

I would like to filter the table in R that includes the list of URLs with their related metadata (title tags, meta descriptions), based on keywords in a CSV file.

I would like it to act as a database, that searches for the keywords in the CSV file and when it matches the list of URLs/metadata, a new column is added based on the group the keyword is attributed to.

I have tried to read in a csv file, adding it to a variety of different "filter %like% [csv_df]"-eque options but it doesn't seem to work.

```
urls <- read.csv("urls.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% as.data.frame() 

keyword_inclusions <- read.csv("keyword_inclusions.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Can you please share a code snippet of what you've tried so far?  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3277821) for some details.

Comment: As @sboysel states, you should provide example data and code (which you have a snippet of in the above). Directly related to your question though - what is the relation between keywords (your objective sounds like it could be solved by joining the tables before grouping and filtering)? Also, what exactly do you mean by a new column is added based on the group the keyword is attributed to (don't you already know the keyword categories beforehand)? You might have more luck here if you rewrite your question with your objective a bit more clearly stated.